# Values from fields in templates

Tags: templating, field, fieldtypes

I have categories in my cms.

[image]

How do I gets a list of these value into my templates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is all covered in the [Craft CMS documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/multi-select-fields.html#working-with-multi-select-field-data):

```
{% for option in entry.<FieldHandle> %}
    Label: {{ option.label }}
    Value: {{ option }} or {{ option.value }}
{% endfor %}
```